# Protege: What's difference between individual type and individual property assertions?

Tags: owl, protege, object-property

On Protege 5, we can make an assertion on a individual by two different ways.

```
individual1 type property1 value individual2
individual1 property1 individual2
```

[image]

I don't know what's the difference of them.

Plus, is there a way to put some restrictions on individuals in terms of cardinality? Based on Open World Assumption, It would be interpreted that the individual1 may have other relations. I want to make the individual1 only have one kind of property, ie. property1.